# Envelope-following bandpass filter?

Tags: filter, filtering, plug-ins

Anyone use one as a plug-in that they like the sound of? I'm specifically working on something where this would save exactly one metric butt-ton of automation...

Comment: What exactly are you using it for?

Comment: I'm experimenting using crashing surf with an automated bandpass filter as a means to create a whistling wind effect. 

Answer (score 3):

Soundtoys [Filter Freak](http://www.soundtoys.com/products/FilterFreak/) is great.

Comment: Thank you, @Justin: I've not grabbed any of Soundtoys' goodies yet, despite their rep, so I had *totally* overlooked Filter Freak. Great option!

Comment: Using it right now…amazing results with minimal effort!

Answer (score 2):

I've been messing with the Bluecat plugins - at first they seem like straight forward level & spectrum analysis meters but they can output MIDI from their analysis!! So you could feed the level as a control voltage across to whatever filter plugin you like... 
http://www.bluecataudio.com

In the real/analogue world I personally like the Doepfer A119 module ;) Its intriguing that an analogue synth technique that has been around for decades is relatively rare in the virtual world....

Comment: Whoa, that's pretty unique! Super cool. Could totally see routing that data into this Waldorf Pulse on my desk..! :-)

Answer (score 0):

+1 for Filter Freak!

Answer (score 0):

I think Live has one build inside. If you dont want to use Live, you can use the PSP Nitro for it, one of my fav. plugins at the moment